# Is there a derivative of LMP-103S, called LMP-103, that has even higher performance?

Tags: fuel, monopropellant

I found [this](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1270&context=smallsat) PDF while searching for any and all info related to LMP-103S, which you can read more about in [my related question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/is-lmp-103s-truly-a-viable-replacement-for-hydrazine).

In the PDF, if you scroll down to page 4, you will find a chart listing various performances of several thrusters, starting from 0.5 N to 220 N. If you look at that last one, it actually lists the fuel as *"LMP-103"*, not *"LMP-103**S**"*, and the exit velocity listed is 2.8 km/s for a specific impulse of 285 seconds!

Is this a typo? Or is there some new derivative fuel lurking out there that has this amazing performance? I hope so, and tend to think so because that listed Isp is a rather big jump from the others. I really hope it is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think LMP - 103 is Liquid Mono propellant which is a green monopropellant which is ionic salt liquid higher density than commercial hydrazine propellant. It is less toxic and high performance than hydrazine. LMP 103 is a Ammonium Di Nitramide (ADN)  based monopropellant with water and fuel component can be used as better replacement for highly toxic hydrazine propellant. This fuel blend is mostly preferred by ESA and ESA has flown a different type of ADN fuel blend in PRISMA project in 2010 by Swedish Spacy Agency. Theoretical maximum Isp for this kind of propellant blend is about 280s.