# What "green" propellant powers Curie, the engine on RocketLab's payload kickstage?

Tags: fuel, rocketlab, monopropellant, green-propellant, curie

Upon news of RocketLab's successful flight of the Electron launch vehicle, it was announced that not only had they deployed the three onboard payloads into the desired orbit, they had done so using a newly developed kick stage powered by an engine called *Curie*:

> The successful launch of Rocket Lab’s Electron rocket Jan. 20 also tested a kick stage designed to circularize the orbits of its satellite payloads. [...] The heart of the kick stage is Curie, an engine developed by Rocket Lab.

From SpaceNews' article: *[Rocket Lab launch also tested new kick stage](http://spacenews.com/rocket-lab-launch-also-tested-new-kick-stage/)*.

An image of the [Curie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_(rocket_engine)) kick stage can be seen in this photo supplied by RocketLab:

[image]

However, the *kicker* is that this doesn't appear to be using the typical monopropellant of Hydrazine:

> The heart of the kick stage is Curie, an engine developed by Rocket Lab. Beck described the engine, capable of performing multiple burns, as 3D-printed **and using an unspecified “green” monopropellant**. [Emphasis mine]

What is this green monopropellant? Is it similar to [AF-M315E](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/why-did-spacex-choose-to-use-hydrazine-over-newer-green-propellants-for-dragon), [LMP-103S](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10032/is-there-a-derivative-of-lmp-103s-called-lmp-103-that-has-even-higher-performa/20463#20463), or something else entirely?

Comment: Reddit chatter suggests (with no citations) either AF-M315E or RocketLabs' patented "viscous liquid monopropellant (VLM)", a thixotropic goo: https://www.google.com/patents/US20120234196 -- personally, though, and also without citations, I think if it were anything more exciting than peroxide they'd be bragging about it.

Comment: @RussellBorogove it's clear from that patent that the oxidizer is some kind of organic nitrate, not peroxide. Better specific impulse than peroxide but not particularly exciting. It's also clear that they're premixing fuel and oxidiser, which has some safety implications.

Comment: I'm saying I suspect Curie's propellant is something old-school like peroxide monoprop rather than VLM, because if they were using their patented goo for the kick motor they'd want to say so, not that peroxide is part of VLM.

Comment: JAXA SHP163 might be another interesting candidate, which is HAN-based, like AF-M315E. However, it is unlikely Curie is running either on HAN or ADN based propellants as these have not been scaled up that big

Comment: Another ADN based candidate could be FLP-106, developed in Sweden again, but unlikely to be scaled up either.

Comment: Also, Curie does NOT use VLM as per Peter Beck: https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/8a1wwy/i_am_peter_beck_ask_me_anything_about_rocket_lab/dwvf7yz/

Comment: [According to the August 2020 Payload User's Guide, Curie uses an unspecified *bipropellant*](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/assets/Uploads/Rocket-Lab-Launch-Payload-Users-Guide-6.5.pdf), not a monopropellant.

Comment: per [Peter Beck Tweets](https://twitter.com/Peter_J_Beck/status/1296209555798425601?cxt=HHwWgoCo_aXuh_0jAAAA) the biprop combo is storable, hypergolic, and [310s Isp at 200:1 exit ratio](https://twitter.com/Peter_J_Beck/status/1296211126636523520?s=20)

Comment: HAN/ADN were originally developed by militaries, as liquid gun propellants. There is the distinct possibility that stuff is going on in the Black world (or, it did). The argument for NASA’s green propellant mission tacitly included the release of flight results to industry that the Black world would not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the composition of the monopropellant is a trade secret per Wikipedia's [Curie (rocket engine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_(rocket_engine)):

> While Rocket Lab is not known to have specified the monopropellant used by Curie, in 2012 Rocket Lab demonstrated the use of a non-toxic Viscous Liquid Monopropellant (VLM) that it had developed.

So I don't believe that we can actually know. We do know from Peter Beck that Curie runs on [some hypergolic fuel](https://twitter.com/Peter_J_Beck/status/1296209555798425601?cxt=HHwWgoCo_aXuh_0jAAAA), but that is all.

---

Additionally, in the years since Electron's first launch, RocketLab have developed a bipropellant version of the engine - see [Electron's Payload User Guide (PUG)](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/assets/Uploads/Rocket-Lab-Launch-Payload-Users-Guide-6.5.pdf).  By inspection of the same PUG, they may even have phased out the use of the original monopropellant engine.  However, the composition of the bipropellant is also unknown.

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom as Russell Borogove pointed out in comments on the question, [the Electron user's guide](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/assets/Uploads/Rocket-Lab-Launch-Payload-Users-Guide-6.5.pdf) only indicates a biprop kick stage (page 10).  I think that's an indication that the monoprop version is no longer in use, though admittedly a weak one.  Your point that the OP was asking about the monoprop engine is 100% valid though.

Comment: I will keep the monoprop as Infinte Maelstrom is correct. The purpose of answers is to answer the OPs question @ErinAnne